# Formatting USB-stick to NTFS or FAT32

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, android

After reformatting my USB-stick it became unreadable by Android filesystem. Android Supports only NTFS or FAT32, but whenever I try to format USB-drive from Ubuntu to any of the types I can see flag "msftdata" in GParted. I believe this is the problem. Windows and Ubuntu can read it fine though. Ubuntu filesystem seems to struggle to determine USB-stick's filesystem, but can read it. I tried to reformat into different types, change flags, but no success so far.

**UPD**I was able to read USB-stick using StickMount app from Play Store. I would still prefer Android to mount it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wipe first 1 MB of your USB stick:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1
```

and then reformat it to FAT32 again.

Be careful though: make sure that `/dev/sdb` is really your flash drive, or you will kill contents of your real hard drive!

Comment: I'm not sure which partition table I should create. I tried "gpt" but no luck with android reading it.

Comment: Use msdos partition table. Almost nothing supports gpt on flash drives (Linux does).

Comment: for some weird reason it is still unreadable on android. No idea what can be preventing it from reading.